# Python handle custom exception from java web service

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, suds

I have a java web service and python client using suds. My server raises custom exceptions which I would like to handle in the python script. Is it possible to catch them or it always will be caught as suds.WebFault exception?

Answer (score 1):

[suds.WebFault has](http://jortel.fedorapeople.org/suds/doc/suds-pysrc.html#WebFault) fault field that has information about fault.

```
except suds.WebFault, e:
    print e.fault.faultstring
    print e.document
```

You can have your program to analyze server custom exception from WebFault and create new exception class(es) for every specific server exception then catch `suds.WebFault` exception, read server exception details and raise your custom exception.

```
class MyException(suds.WebFault):
    pass


def convertServerException(e):
    if e.fault.faultstring == 'exception1':
        return MyException()
        #...add more exception handling cases here

#...
try:
#...make a WebService call
except suds.WebFault, e:
    print e
    print e.fault
    raise convertServerException(e)
```